# How to Populate visible cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I have the table below which I filter on the size column and want to update col I with a number.  I have searched for answer but find it hard to relate the cose in the answers back to my requiuirement

[image]

This table is called APD_Table and is in a sheet called DATA -Product Validation.

The value in need to populate into column I is in a variable call Packsize which is set as follows..PackSize = PackListWs.Range("e" & sc).Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the visible range with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

```
    PackSize = PackListWs.Range("e" & sc).Value
    Dim objTab As ListObject, visRange As Range
    Set objTab = Sheetst("DATA-Product Validation").ListObjects("APD_Table")
    Set visRange = objTab.DataBodyRange.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRange Is Nothing Then
        visRange.Value = PackSize
    End If
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: This is working fine thanks - only issue is that if the filter doesn't find anything the set visrange fails with 1004 error - I am thinking all i need is an ON ERROR THEN RESUME statement before it

Comment: Working perfectly! I needed to add code after the SET VISRANGe to check if any rows were displayed - if there were no rows then I bypass the  visRange.Value = PackSize processing... thanks again for your help